# DTLS on Android

Tags: android, ssl, dtls

I recently discovered DTLS, however can't seem to find any Android libraries or APIs for its use akin to what [`SSLSocket`](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket) is for TLS/SSL. I'm fairly new to Android dev, so any tutorials or posts would also be super helpful :)

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2914151/9063935) similar post, however its fairly old and I was wondering what libraries / APIs there are to offer 10 years later. Thanks!

Comment: Related: [Difference between DTLS and TLS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15331294/295004)

Answer (score 1):

(Too late, I saw, you have already read the other question which points also to Scandium. So I guess, that is not the answer you're looking for ;-) )

You may try [Scandium](https://github.com/eclipse/californium/tree/master/scandium-core), the Java-DTLS library of the Eclipse Open Source Project **Californium**. If you have any questions about that, don't hesitate to open an issue there.